# Input image size CNN Tensorflow

Tags: image, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am feeding my CNN with image size of 2048x2048. However I accidentaly forgot to change the size of the input:

```
img_width, img_height = 32, 32
input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
```

I was wondering why does the training still run even if the input images are larger than 32x32 pixels? Or does the CNN only recognizes part of the images?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most implementations of convolutional layers will operate on any sized images. For 2D convolutions with `padding="SAME"`, the output size of any convolutional layer will be `[batch_size, input_height // stride[0], input_width // stride[1], filters]` (valid padding just means you lose a few pixels on each boundary depending on the kernel size).

Similarly, the number of weights involved in the kernel is `filters_in * filters_out * np.prod(kernel_size)`, which is independent of input size (bias is just `filters_out`).

To do tasks such as classification, most CNNs use a spatial pooling layer at the end (e.g. `tf.reduce_mean(features, axis=(1, 2))`) which reduces the output of any input image batch to `[batch_size, n_filters_out]`, regardless of input size, followed by some dense layers to regress to logits.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Maybe there is slightly misunderstanding. So first of all, what does this line mean?

    img_width, img_height = 32, 32
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)

Comment: Doesn't it mean specify the width and height of the input image?

Comment: That's how I'd read it, but that's different to how it is used (you haven't shown how it is used). Building a convolutional layer requires constructing the kernel, and some values in the input size are required to be specified for this (the number of filters coming in). The others are likely ignored, or possibly used to compute the output size... but if that output size has elements which get ignored (e.g. if it gets fed into another convolutional layer or spatial pooling op) then that likely won't cause issues.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer again. Basically those lines can be found in many CIFAR-10 recognition examples. But when this line "img_width, img_height = 32, 32 input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)" for the training, which area in the training images (image size is 2048x2048 pixels) will be taken for calculating the weights?

Comment: Depends on your network. Some purely convolutional networks have a series of convolutions followed by a spatial pooling layer, e.g. average pooling, and if its not throwing errors this is likely the case. So if your convs map (batch_size, H_in, W_in, 3) -> (batch_size, H_out, W_out, n_filters), then after pooling you'll just have (batch_size, n_filters) features, which can be passed into dense/fully connected layers regardless of the image size.